# Some approach to work with big data cases

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, performance, design-patterns, architecture

At the company that I work we have some problems with performance loading the data of database.
Our ERP works with a big database and we need to make some complex queries.
We are using C# following the DDD pattern and in the front-end we are using ASP.NET MVC.

The example that I'm talking is that:
We have alot of lists (grids) in the system where the data is loaded by ajax. But everytime that a user enter in some page like that (an html page), we need to make a query in the database.

Its important to say that this data aren't only for "query". This data is constantly changed by the users.

My doubt is if you have any sugestion to how we can minimize this problem. I already have searching some solutions of cache in the server side, but I don't have any experience working with cache in high complex scenarios.

Very thanks,
Renan Cunha.

Comment: Try to find out where exactly your bottleneck is. It's very likely that just a few queries are causing your problems. Perhaps you can fix the performance issue by optimizing those few queries (or by adding/removing indexes on your database).  Or perhaps your problem is that you are selecting and returning too much data? If your users enter the page and you immediately fetch thousands of records, you might want to consider introducing paging.

Comment: Yeh, we already use pagination...The problem is that almost queries are complex...

Comment: Find the complex queries that take most time. (It might very well be the case that a single query is the culprit of your performance problem). Then try to fine-tune those queries. If you use Oracle, perhaps you can use hints. If you have many many joins, replace the query with a stored procedure where you execute simpler queries and join the results (I've had success with this approach in the past). Throw away your slow query and write it anew using a different approach. Check the execution plan to find full table scans etc etc.

Comment: Would this question be better fitted maybe for http://dba.stackexchange.com/ or even http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ?